# How to evaluate the multi-line export command to set environment variables

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script, generate some output just as what the `echo` below does. How to export the two environment variables `a` and `b`?

I tried

```
echo -e "export a=3\nexport b=4"|bash
```

or

```
echo -e "export a=3\nexport b=4"|eval
```

or

```
echo -e "export a=3\nexport b=4"|exec
```

Neither works. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pipe the command to a program, the program runs in a child process, so none of its environment changes affect the original shell.

Use `eval` and give the string as an argument. Use `;` to separate commands rather than newline.

```
eval 'export a=3; export b=4'
```